# How to put name to label?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlabel

I am a student programmer and I really need to fix this code to able to finish my project.

Is there any other way to put a unique name to this for loop labels?

Because whenever a user click one of the labels, the text will change its color. Not all the labels, only the one that user had clicked.

```
public void addComponentsToPane(final JPanel pane) {
    if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    c.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 5, 5);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    if (shouldFill) {
        //natural height, maximum width
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
        if (z == 14) {
            y++;
            x = 0;
            z = 0;
        }
        try {

            label = new JLabel("# " + i);
            labels();
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = x;
            c.gridy = y;
            pane.add(label, c);
            x++;
            z++;
            set_x = x;
            set_y = y;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    tableNum = i;
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int UserInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Number of Table:"));
                int i;
                for (i = tableNum; i <= (tableNum + UserInput) - 1; i++) {
                    if (z == 14) {
                        set_y++;
                        set_x = 0;
                        z = 0;
                    }
                    try {

                        label = new JLabel("# " + i);

                        labels();
                        c.weightx = 0.5;
                        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                        c.gridx = set_x;
                        c.gridy = set_y;
                        pane.add(label, c);
                        set_x++;
                        z++;
                        lbl[i] = label;
                     //   lbl[i].setForeground(Color.red);
                        System.out.print(lbl[i].getText());
                        //   set_x = x;
                        //    set_y = y;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }

                }
                tableNum = i;
                frame.revalidate();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLease Input Digits Only", "Input                       Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    });

}

private void labels() {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imagePath + labelIconName);
    icon.getImage().flush();
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    label.setForeground(Color.black);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //  label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //    String[] option = {"Available", "Occupied", "Reserved"};

            // choose = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Table :"+label.getText() + , "Choose transaction", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, option, option[0]);
            System.out.print(label.getName());
            centerScreen();

            selectAllMenu();
            jDialogMenu.show();

            //  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Pls help and ASAP earn you no help here. Showing respect and most importantly what you tried will. [FAQ] (On a second note, detailing what you exactly want would help too. Frankly, I don't know what you're asking, even though I've seen my share of questions...)

Comment: what do you mean by `unique namea`

Comment: Minor hint: you should get rid of irrelevant code in your code samples to make them more readable. (In this case, all the layout code and most of the Label styling etc, only keep the basic setting them up, add some dummy text, and the parts of the code that should be working but don't.)

Comment: That said, in your action listener for `btn`, you seem to be creating new labels and adding them to the panel, with code copy-pasted *[sigh]* from the first time you do that. Is this intentional, or shouldn't you just change the foreground color of the existing labels in `lbl`?

Comment: Just a side node, if you use **catch-all** `catch (Exception ex)` (which is never advisable), at least add add something like `System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace)` to the block.

Comment: im sorry for the try catch. this is my first time here in stack OverFlow.. i want to add another set of label in my panel whenever button is click. therefore when i have 10 labels .when button is click  another 5 label is added so it will become 15 labels inside the panel. now the thing is i want to set a name for each of the panel. So i can set a foreground to each labels. . tnx for the comments

Comment: @PM77-1 `System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace)` won't compile, but `ex.printStackTrace()` might.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - Sorry. Quick fingers: I was thinking of `printStackTrace` and `getMessage` at the same time.

Comment: @Jon, still waiting for you to reply to the suggestions given. Did they help or not?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to set a name for each of the panel. So i can set a foreground to each labels.

You don't need a unique name. You need to add a MouseListener to every label that you create. Then is the mousePressed() event you can change the foreground of the label clicked by using generic code. For example:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        label.setForeground(...);
    }
}

...

label.addMouseListener( ml );
```